# Return ActiveRecord Relation from a raw SQL query using parametrized queries to speed up response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails model called `VideoEventBundle` which contains individual events. This is associated with a `VideoMeasurement` model via foreign key, and the `VideoMeasurement` model itself is one of the possible polymorphic child models of `Measurement`.

SQL schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.video_event_bundles (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    video_measurement_id bigint,
    events jsonb DEFAULT '[]'::jsonb
);

CREATE TABLE public.video_measurements (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE public.measurements (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    customer_id bigint NOT NULL,
    actable_type character varying,
    actable_id bigint
);
```

Now, in the context of an API that primarily returns measurements, I also want to export all video event bundles that belong to the measurements a user has selected/filtered. For that I have a general method that sets `@measurements` to an ActiveRecord relation based on the user's filters. For instance:

```rb
@measurements = Measurement.where(customer_id: params[:customer_id])
```

To get the actual event bundles, I used to have this query:

```
    VideoEventBundle.find_by_sql([
      "SELECT video_event_bundles.*
        FROM video_event_bundles
          JOIN video_measurements ON video_event_bundles.video_measurement_id = video_measurements.id
          JOIN measurements ON video_measurements.id = measurements.actable_id
        WHERE measurements.actable_type = 'VideoMeasurement'
        AND measurements.id IN (?)
      ",
      @measurements.select(:id)
    ])
```

The problem is that this returns an array of objects, and not an ActiveRecord relation. The issue with that is that in the case of unfiltered measurements, that array would be huge. Since the API is paginated, I need to be able to pass limit/offset to that method, and consequently, I have to actually return an ActiveRecord relation.

Now I've seen multiple questions here related to returning that from a raw SQL query:

- [Rails - how to convert output of find_by_sql (array) to an ActiveRecord relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65829729/rails-how-to-convert-output-of-find-by-sql-array-to-an-activerecord-relation)
- [How to chain raw SQL queries in Rails OR how to return an ActiveRecord_Relation from a raw SQL query in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47893902/how-to-chain-raw-sql-queries-in-rails-or-how-to-return-an-activerecord-relation)
- [find_by_sql to something that returns an activeRecords relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326662/find-by-sql-to-something-that-returns-an-activerecords-relation)

But I can't manage to use the `(?)` parameter to actually replace the IDs:

```rb
sql = <<-SQL
      SELECT video_event_bundles.*
        FROM video_event_bundles
          JOIN video_measurements ON video_event_bundles.video_measurement_id = video_measurements.id
          JOIN measurements ON video_measurements.id = measurements.actable_id
        AND measurements.id IN (?)
    SQL

    VideoEventBundle.select("*").from("(#{sql}) AS video_event_bundles", @measurements.select(:id))
```

This raises the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 5:         AND measurements.id IN (?)
```

I guess I can't work my way around this by starting the query with `@measurements.join(…)`?

Comment: Could you post the resulting SQL-Query? Could you try to swap "AND measurements.id IN (?)" with "AND measurements.id IN ?" (delete the paranthesises)

Comment: @zaphodbln_ That gives me the same syntax error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "?"`

Comment: Solution found, I guess a version of the XY problem …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to just use:

```rb
VideoEventBundle
  .joins(video_measurement: :measurement)
  .where(measurement: { id: @measurements.select(:id) })
```

---

If not we can definitely accomplish your needed SQL using AR's builtin mechanisms and a little bit of Arel:

```rb
measurement_table = Measurement.arel_table
vm_table = VideoMeasurement.arel_table
measurement_join = measurement_table.join(vm_table)
   .on(vm_table[:id].eq(measurement_table[:actable_id])
         .and(measurement_table[:actable_type].eq('VideoMeasurement')))
VideoEventBundle
  .joins(:video_measurement)
  .joins(measurement_join)
  .where(measurements: {id: @measurements.select(:id)})
```

This will result in

```
SELECT
    video_event_bundles.*
FROM 
    video_event_bundles
    INNER JOIN video_measurements 
      ON video_event_bundles.video_measurement_id = video_measurements.id
    INNER JOIN measurements 
      ON video_measurements.id = measurements.actable_id 
         AND measurements.actable_type = 'VideoMeasurement'
WHERE 
   measurements.id IN (
     SELECT 
        measurements.id
     FROM 
        measurements
     WHERE
        measurements.customer_id = 1234
   )
```

Comment: Your first suggestion gives the error: `Can't join 'VideoEventBundle' to association named 'video_measurements'; perhaps you misspelled it?` — because it `belongs_to :video_measurement` (i.e. 1:1 relationship). When I change it to `VideoEventBundle.joins(video_measurement: :measurement).where(measurement: {id: @measurements.select(:id)})` I get the right response! So what I do now, I first filter and paginate the `@measurements`, and then use that query to only retreive the matching event bundles.

Comment: @slhck I would paginate the results of the entire query since that is what you are returning. Additionally I am not sure how your application is built but the prefiltering of `Measurement` to be used in the `IN()` is technically unnecessary since the measurements table is part of this query. Instead you could pass all of those conditions through the WHERE clause directly. e.g. `where(measurement: { customer_id: params[:customer_id]})` this will avoid the need for the subquery.

Comment: If I put that in the where clause, I think I would have to duplicate the code; most other routes are based on the `measurement` as the main class. So I have a dozen possible filters/queries set up to get `@measurements`, like: `@measurements = @measurements.where(…) if params[:customer_id]` and so on. I don't think I can do this generically when now the measurement is a join table?